# Does the event notification work for expired envelopes that now have void status?

Tags: java, docusignapi

I have a webhook listener for event notification for the following statuses. 
Completed, declined and voided. 
Will my listener work for expired envelopes too which have a status of void after expiration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should receive notification for the expired envelopes. Please make sure to select **"Envelope Voided Reason"** inside **"include"** section so that to identify if envelope expired or was voided. Also note, for expired envelope you will get envelope status as Voided.